# How to read Int64 values from sqlite database?

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

My table and row look like below;

```
Table : Visit
Column : VisitDate
Value : 634993344000000000
```

VisitDate column holds an Int64 value (such as DateTime.Now.Ticks)

while I am reading this from database, SQLite cannot detect whether column is Int64 value.
My code is;

```
switch (sqlite3_column_type(statement,i))
      {
         case SQLITE_INTEGER:
                intValue  = (int)sqlite3_column_int(statement, i);
                colNameChar = (const char *)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                colName =  [NSString stringWithCString:colNameChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                colValue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger: intValue];
                break;
        case SQLITE_FLOAT:
                dblValue = (double)sqlite3_column_double(statement, i);
                colNameChar = (const char *)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                colName =  [NSString stringWithCString:colNameChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                colValue  = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: dblValue];
                break;
         case SQLITE_TEXT:
                 strValue = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
                 colNameChar = (const char *)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                 colName =  [NSString stringWithCString:colNameChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                 colValue = [NSString stringWithCString:strValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        break;
          case SQLITE_BLOB:
                  strValue = (const char *)sqlite3_column_value(statement, i);
                  colNameChar = (const char *)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                  colName =  [NSString stringWithCString:colNameChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  colValue = [NSString stringWithCString:strValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  break;
           case SQLITE_NULL:
                  strValue = nil;
                  colNameChar = (const char *)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                  colName =  [NSString stringWithCString:colNameChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                  colValue = [[NSObject alloc] init];
                  break;
            default:
                   strValue = (const char *)sqlite3_column_value(statement, i);
                   colNameChar = (const char *)sqlite3_column_name(statement, i);
                   colName =  [NSString stringWithCString:colNameChar encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                   colValue = [NSString stringWithCString:strValue encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    break;
       }
```

Debugger enters case of SQLITE_INTEGER and produces a garbage value (something like -2323423).
How can I get correct value?

Comment: `intValue  = (int)sqlite3_column_int(statement, i)` - are you sure that on your platform `int` is 64-bit?

Comment: No no, `intValue = (int)sqlite3_column_int(statement, i)` this assginment is incorrect. I know how to read it (`longValue = (long)sqlite3_column_int64(statement, i);`). Bu the problem is, `sqlite_column_type` cannot detect the value is int or int64(long).

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_blob.html

Comment: It did not anything help.

Comment: so,what you are expecting in which case it should go?

Comment: try this function: sqlite3_column_int64 instead of sqlite3_column_int

Comment: it's possible solution but what about normal int values such as 3,5,90,1000. Does sqlite3_column_int64 cause an issue or warning?

Comment: I don't think it will cause any issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQLite, *all* integer values are 64-bit values.
It is common to use `sqlite3_column_int` only because most applications already know that their values do fit into 32 bits (or have copy-pasta'd that code from some other application that made this assumption).

If you want to check whether a `SQLITE_INTEGER` value will fit into 32 or 64 bits, you have to call `sqlite3_column_int64` first and check the result.